# Including function in React useEffect Dependency Array causes Unwanted Function Runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

In my React Typescript app, I am using a `useEffect` to call `eventTracker` whenever `wallet.address` changes.

```
const wallet = useWallet();
const eventTracker = useAnalyticsEventTracker();

useEffect(() => {
  if (wallet?.address) {
    eventTracker('Wallet', 'Connect', wallet?.address);
    console.log(wallet.address);
  }
}, [wallet]);
```

Both my IDE and browser console are giving the warning

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'eventTracker'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I am unsure either my approach or the linter suggestion is correct, because adding `eventTracker` to the dependency array causes the function passed into `useEffect` to run 10 times when the application starts, instead of just once.

What do folks recommend be done here?

---

Here's the hook:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

const useAnalyticsEventTracker = () => {
  const eventTracker = (
    category: string,
    action: string,
    label: string,
  ) => {
    ReactGA.event({ category, action, label });
  };

  return eventTracker;
};

export default useAnalyticsEventTracker;
```

Comment: Does `useAnalyticsEventTracker` call an external system, such as a database or external API?

Comment: @PsiKai Yes, it calls an external API (e.g. google analytics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your linter suggestion is correct, you just have to apply some memoization to avoid re-rendering.

Upon each render, `eventTracker` is re-created because you call `useAnalyticsEventTracker` that creates a new callback. Therefore, having it included in the dependency array will cause re-triggers of your `useEffect`, as it keeps changing.

You can solve it in many ways. One way is to use `useCallback` in order to memoize this function so it will be created only 1 time:

```js
const useAnalyticsEventTracker = () => {
  const eventTracker = useCallback((
    category: string,
    action: string,
    label: string,
  ) => {
    ReactGA.event({ category, action, label });
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Barak said the eventTracker is recreated each render. The useffect get this initial version of the function which is being discarded each render.

Adding it as a dependency would trigger the use effect each render.

Alternatively, to memoization you could import useAnalyticsEventTracker & call it instead of declaring and calling eventTracker. That way the function is not being updated.
Hope that helps!